# How to setup a RequestHandler for images with VaadinServlet

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to have a `RequestHandler` to be able to dynamically create images at say `myDomain/images/id8938748.jpg` and at the same handle all other traffic through the standard `VaadinServlet`. To do this I understand that I need to put the `RequestHandler` in the `VaadinServlet` as [explained here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/3072331/3174810) by extending it such as:

```
public class MyCustomServlet extends VaadinServlet 
{
        @Override
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            getService().addSessionInitListener(new SessionInitListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException 
                {
                    event.getSession().addRequestHandler(myCustomRequestHandlerForImages);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

My problem is how do you register the new `MyCustomServlet`? I looked at doing it in the `web.xml` but I just can't seem to get it right.

My `RequestHandler` is simply:

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession session, VaadinRequest request, VaadinResponse response) throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Test it's being called");
}
```

For the `web.xml` I have:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyCustomVaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.test.MyCustomVaadinServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyCustomVaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I then have the other `Servlet` defined in the `UI` code with annotations:

```
public class MyUI extends UI
{
  @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
  @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class, widgetset = "com.MyWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet 
  {
  }
  ...
}
```

When I call domain itself it all works as expected and my Vaadin application works. But when I call domain/images or domain/images/randomText I get an empty page and the `System.out.println` statements are NOT outputted. Basically the `RequestHandler` is NOT called.

I have also tried things like mapping to `/images/*` and `/app/*` but that didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you display those images in your Vaadin UI by using for example the [`Image`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Image.html) component, you could use a [`Resource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Resource.html). There are several resource implementations available:

- [`ThemeResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/ThemeResource.html): add your file (e.g. image) to your theme and use this to reference to the image.
- [`ÈxternalResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/ExternalResource.html): A file on a URL.
- [`ClassResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/ClassResource.html): A file on your classpath, Vaadin servlet serves the file to the browser.
- [`FileResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/FileResource.html): A file on the filesystem of the server. Vaadin servlet  serves the file to the browser.
- [`StreamResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/StreamResource.html): Generate your file from an `InputStream`. Vaadin servlet serves the file to the browser.

  ```
  Image image = new Image();
  image.setSource(new ThemeResource("path/is/relative/to/the/theme/folder.png"));
  ```

A valid alternative is also to do so that you create a regular servlet that generates and serves the files. Then you cannot map the Vaadin Servlet to the context root anymore. Then you could use an ExternalResource to reference to the files in your Vaadin code:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setSource(new ExternalResource("/images/id8938748.jpg"));
```

Your servlet mapping would look for example as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyImageServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyVaadinServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyVaadinServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm trying to directly link the image and not have it in a UI. Within the UI is very simple. I want to do it within Vaadin so that I can take advantage of the session management (you can only see your images) and hence use the same session authentication.

Now I did try to do this with the servlet mapping as you suggested but it didn't work for me. I tried to remove the wild card and do /images/* and /app/* (last line of question) but this didn't work.The request handler was never called...

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Servlets deployed from the same war file share the same HttpSession so that can be used to for storing user information.

Comment: That's exactly why I wanted to use a Servlet ;)

Answer (score 0):

My only solution, which I don't think is the right solution, is to create another `UI` class such that:

```
public class MyImagesUI extends UI 
{
    @WebServlet(value = "/images/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyImagesUI.class, widgetset = "com.MyWidgetset")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet 
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
    {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().addRequestHandler(new RequestHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession session, VaadinRequest request, VaadinResponse response) throws IOException 
            {
                System.out.println("Test output");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code does work and shows the output to the console. From there I can `response.setContentType("...")` and do as I need and it works as well.

Now my understanding is that this isn't the "proper way", that the proper way is through a `Servlet`, but in the meantime this does work very well.